# Batch Random Number Generator - Generates Same Number as Before

Tags: if-statement, random, batch-file

Basically, what is happening is my code continues to generate the same number. I have turned echo off to see the problem and the actual %random% variable is changing, but it seems like it does the math and says "No, it's really this number." Here's the code:

```
set /a num=(24 * %random%) / 32768 + 1
```

I have tested that code by itself and it works fine. However when I add my if statements* to the code, it goes all whack. So, the question is, how do I fix this and why is it happening?

*My if statements:

```
if "%num%"=="24" (
  echo X
  set /p ans=
  if "%ans%"=="litin" (
    echo.
    echo Correct!
    pause>nul
    goto generate
  )
)
```

All of my if statements look like that.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might have an issue with variable expansion.  Assuming you are doing this stuff in a loop.

Try adding `setlocal` at the top of your program like this:

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
```

And `endlocal` at the end of your program:

```
endlocal
```

Now, when you need to use a variable that is changing inside a loop, use the `!` syntax instead of `%`:

```
if "!num!"=="24" (
  echo X
  set /p ans=
  if "!ans!"=="litin" (
    echo.
    echo Correct!
    pause>nul
    goto generate
  )
)
```

Comment: `!` literal must be escaped when delayed expansion is enabled: `echo Correct^^!`. Not just loops require delayed expansion. Concatenated commands, or multiple commands within parentheses, as in the IF statement, have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `EQU` for comparing numbers. So try this

```
if "%num%" EQU 24 ( 
    ...
)
```